# Detect visitor adwords keyword with google adwords and analytics in website?

Tags: php, session, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am using google adwords and analytics.

Is it possible to detect visitor google adwords keyword coming from google adwords to my website?

For example:
1. In google.com i search "cheap car"
2. I clicked a google adwords advertising in google result
3. I redirected to my website

In website **i want to catch the "cheap car" keyword from visitor** and save it to .php session for learn which visitor is came with which "keyword", is it possible?

Comment: also looking for a solution for this, if you ended up finding a working solution please do share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in the *triggering keyword*, it's probably easiest to use the ValueTrack parameter `{keyword}` and decorate all your destination / final URLs accordingly, e.g. `http://www.example.com/?keyword={keyword}`. See [this support article](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447) for more information about ValueTrack.

If you mean the actual *search term* that the visitor used however, that's not possible to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: i used http://www.example.com/?keyword={keyword} but it is not return the correct "google search keyword", it return similar keyword of my search is it normal?

Comment: Like I mentioned, you won't be provided with the actual term that the user entered into Google's search box–instead you'll get the *keyword* of your Adwords account which triggered your ad to appear.

Answer (score 2):

To configure the tracking:

a) connect your adwords and GA accounts:

b) go to your Adwords Account > Account Preferences, click the "edit" link next to Tracking then select the box that says "Destination URL Auto-tagging". Then click Save;

c) Next, go to Analytics tab and try to choose Analytics Settings > Profile Settings > Edit Profile Information; and check "Apply Cost Data", and Save the Changes

You try to add an additional url parameter to the url, you gave at google adwords, then check for the url on your site and store in session or a cookie.

when a user registers, check for this session or cookie that you have created and do accordingly..

Comment: then how can i catch the keyword from visitor after this?